# Adding an anaconda SDK to an Intellij Project

Tags: python, intellij-idea, anaconda, conda

I looked at the Intellij documentation on how to do this -

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/conda-support-creating-conda-environment.html - for which the following is the crux:

[image]

When I follow those steps the `Conda` environment does not show up:

[image]

Out of curiosity I then clicked on the `Python 2.7.14` to see what that would offer:

[image]

So there would actually be the ability to create a `virtualenv`: but that's likely different from `conda`/`anaconda`.

Does anyone have this working in Intellij?  I a on `IJ Ultimate 2017.1`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem previously and it was caused by not having the correct path setup at the time IntelliJ was started.

You should make sure that the folder containing the anaconda 
binaries is in your path before you start IntelliJ.

I believe that when you install Anaconda it will update your .bashrc file, but this only gets applied to the software you run from the shell, it is not applied to software you start from a shortcut in your graphical environment.

If your environment path is set up correctly then you will see "Create Conda Env" as an option in IntelliJ.

Comment: You may be correct: but a related question: from *where* does Intellij get its path on `macos`?  If I just change the `$PATH` in my `.bashrc` that would not likely affect Intellij that is launched from `Spotlight` (on the gui).

Comment: I am trying out the following:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/198282/55242   `sudo launchctl config user path <my path setting>`

Comment: I have to confess I am not a mac expert, but doing a quick search here on SO, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x#588442.

Here they mention that you can edit the file `/etc/launchd.conf` and add the corresponding environment variable setting